# DigitalOcean not updating properly

Tags: git, nginx, digital-ocean, forever

I have a react project that I have uploaded to the Digital ocean. I have an issue where I made some changes to a project. Did a git pull (see the changes on ubuntu server), however, the changes arent' displaying? I destroyed the droplet re did everything but the issue persists. My domain name comes from go daddy if that helps. stopped/restarted forever. Cleared the cache on the browser. Opened the project on a different laptop. I changed an image from jpg to jpeg.

Comment: at least give some link cause you basically want help with trouble shooting.

Comment: The link to my web-page http://lonniemcgill.com/About and my github https://github.com/mcgizmo26/PortfolioSite. On my profile picture should be on my about page.

Comment: bro the changes  are visible now at least I think so, try checking again.

Comment: yeah it turned out to be a compiling issue. Webpack wasn't working. Reinstalled it and it worked fine. Thanks for those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Webpack issue. It wouldn't compile correctly. Finally got it to compile correctly after checking my bundle.